# question on functions

Tags: functions

The function is defined as follows;
$f=\mathbb{Z}^{+}\times\{0,1\}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}$ by 
$$
f(n,m)=\begin{cases}n-1 & \text{if }m=0\\
-n & \text{if }m=1\end{cases}.
$$
I have to show this function is a bijection and then to find the inverse of *f*.

How do I start this? 
Thank you.

Comment: Well, what have you tried?  Where are you getting stuck?  What don't you understand?  We need a bit more to work off of if we're going to try to point you in the right direction.

Comment: In case you do not have intuition for why this is a bijection, try drawing a picture (where $\mathbb Z^+\times\{0,1\}$ can be regarded as two copies of $\mathbb Z^+$).

Comment: I know that it should be proved the function is injective and surjective in order to prove it's bijective and I know how to prove them. But the first place I stuck is what does it mean Z⁺ *{0,1}

Comment: @Grazel: $\mathbb{Z}^+ \times \{0,1\}$ is simply the set of all pairs $(n,m)$, where $n$ is in $\mathbb{Z}^+$, and $m$ is in $\{0 , 1\}$, that is, $m$ is either $0$ or $1$.

Comment: @fuglede Hey, thank you so much. I really didn't notice that. Now I know the rest.

Comment: For example, can you find the inverse of this function? What does this imply?

Answer (score 1):

To show that $f$ is a bijection we must show that it is one-to-one and onto.

One-to-one: Show that if $f(a)=f(b)$ for $a,b\in \mathbb{Z}^+\times\{0,1\}$ then $a=b$.

Hint: Separate the cases for

1) $a,b\in \mathbb{Z}^+\times\{0\}$

2) $a,b\in \mathbb{Z}^+\times\{1\}$

3) $a\in \mathbb{Z}^+\times\{0\}, b\in \mathbb{Z}^+\times\{1\}$ (or vice versa wlog)

Hint: Don't forget about the domain!

Onto: Show that for any $b\in \mathbb{Z}$, we can find an $a\in \mathbb{Z}^+\times\{0,1\}$ such that $f(a)=b$.

Hint: Separate the cases for

1) $b\ge0$

2) $b<0$

Your solution to this section should essentially tell you what the inverse of $f$ is.

Comment: @john-can you please explain the inverse part please.

Comment: Sure. The inverse of $f$ is a function $f^{-1}:\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}^+ \times \{0,1\}$ such that $f^{-1}(y)=x \Longleftrightarrow f(x)=y$. So you're essentially just defining $f^{-1}$ based on what you found in the onto section- given an element of $\mathbb{Z} $, which element of $\mathbb{Z}^+ \times \{0,1\}$ mapped to it?